# ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am a begnner in Hadoop and installed hadoop and hbase successfully.

**On running start-all.sh i am getting jps output as:**

- 28673 NodeManager
- 28084 DataNode
- 27960 NameNode
- 28348 SecondaryNameNode
- 29709 Jps
- 28543 ResourceManager

**On running start-hbase.sh i am getting jps as:**

- 30080 Jps
- 28673 NodeManager
- **29249 HQuorumPeer**
- 28084 DataNode
- 27960 NameNode
- 28348 SecondaryNameNode
- 28543 ResourceManager

**When i am runing hbase shell :**

```
hduser@akki-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/Hbase/hbase-
1.2.5/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-
1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an 
explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.2.5, rd7b05f79dee10e0ada614765bb354b93d615a157, Wed Mar  1 
00:34:48 CST 2017

hbase(main):001:0>
```

**When i am giving it a command to list all the tables it shows output as :**

```
hbase(main):001:0>list


2017-03-31 12:38:40,973 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:41,082 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:41,285 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:41,591 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:42,094 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:43,099 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.
2017-03-31 12:38:45,119 ERROR [main] 
client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: The node /hbase is 
not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the 
value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a 
mismatch with the one configured in the master.

ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been 
written by the master. Check the value configured in 
'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one 
configured in the master.

Here is some help for this command:
List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

hbase> list
hbase> list 'abc.*'
hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
hbase> list 'ns:.*'


hbase(main):002:0>
```

**My hbase-site.xml is :**

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase:rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is `hbase.rootdir`. You have `hbase:rootdir`.

Comment: Still getting the same error ! @franklinsijo

Comment: Restart Hbase after changes, `jps` should list `HMaster` and `HRegionServer` along with `HQuorumPeer`.